# Calculator evaluating expressions erroneously?

Tags: arithmetic

Could you please explain to me why the answer of the equation $(24+3) - \frac{27}{3} \times 5$  is $-18$? How come it was negative when in my calculator it's postive?

Also this equation too, with a modulo problem: $12 \times 2 \div 3 \,  \%  \times 5$ and the answer is $3$ when in fact if you sum it up it's $1.6$. I’m so confused

Comment: For the first, just follow the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).  Simplify the parentheses first to get $27-9\cdot 5$.  Then compute the product to get $27-45$.  Then compute the subtraction to get $-18$.  Note that $(24+3)-(27/3)*5\neq ((24+3)-(27/3))*5$.  It looks like maybe you multiplied both sets of parentheses by five instead of just the second set (*if you did everything left-to-right, you'd have gotten zero, not a positive number, hence my expectation*).

Comment: As for the second, $(12\cdot 2/3)\% 5 = (24/3)\%5=8\%5=3$.  I do not see any interpretation that gives you $1.6$.

Comment: @JMoravitz  He thought % meant division

Comment: There are no percentage on my calculator so i used division

Comment: ...........Why?  If you're cooking a cake and the recipe calls for sugar and you have none, would you use salt in place of it instead?

Comment: @hooely the expression in the second question makes no sense as a "modulo problem". Please ask a separate question and clarify the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one you need to calculate the entire term start with the brackets, then multiplication and then you need to subtract one from the other:

So (24+3=27)-((27/3=9)*5=45)= 27 -45= -18.

The second calculation is you need to know what modulo means. In this particular case you need to calculate $(12\times 2 \div 3) \pmod 5$=  8%5. This means that you'll get a remainder of 3 when you divide 8 by 5.

Comment: wow thanks, but im confused with 45

Comment: 27 divided by 3 is 9 multiplied by 5 is 45

Comment: Can you vote this answer if it was useful?

Comment: thank you  one more question hehe, I don't have some modulo something on my calculator sir, so should i compute it to division?

Comment: Im new here so i don't know how to vote

Comment: Accepting is also good. I think you need a particular number of reputation on this site to cast a vote

Comment: Division and modulo operations are different.

Comment: On a calculator you can use both with a division sign but for the modulo operation you need to look only at the remainder when dividing by a certain number.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it helped you in any way

Comment: Sorry sir but i don't know how to vote nor accept your answer. 

Comment: You just accepted my answer with the green symbol

Comment: Peut-etre tu me comprends si je parle en francais. Donc quand tu appuie le vert symbole a gauche de cette réponse, tu acceptes cette réponse.

Comment: did i vote too?

Comment: no you didn't vote on my question you only accepted it but now you didn't

Comment: it says that votes cast with those 15 reputations